# Any difference between Hardware RAID and Software RAID?

Tags: windows, raid, software-raid

I'm building a new server (Small Business Server 2008), but I can't get the built-in RAID controller (AMD SB700) to work and have basically given up on it ever working with Server 2008. Fine.

**But my question is**... is there any real difference between Hardware (such as [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816132014)) and Software (Window's built in Drive Mirroring) for RAID 1?

Assuming the drives are identical models, etc., it seems that there would be a negligible difference, just based on my guessing/wishfull thinking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [**Software Vs Hardware RAID**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/raid-hardware-vs-raid-software.html) in general; also [at **Serverfault**](https://serverfault.com/questions/214/raid-software-vs-hardware).
- Short [**RAID 1** discussion](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?p=6320818) (CentOS context).
- Serverfault: [**Build a software raid 1 on windows XP**](https://serverfault.com/questions/14439/build-a-software-raid-1-on-windows-xp) might also be useful for software RAID 1.
- Serverfault: [**How do I differentiate “fake RAID” from real RAID?**](https://serverfault.com/questions/9244/how-do-i-differentiate-fake-raid-from-real-raid)

Comment: Ah ha, didn't think to try Server Fault

Comment: yes, who could *possibly* imagine asking a server-related question on a site named "Server Fault"?! :)

Answer (score 8):

A few obvious differences:

- With software RAID you are limited to the SATA ports on your motherboard. Some RAID cards allow, say, 10 SATA drives to be connected.
- Software RAID uses additional CPU time, whereas a hardware RAID offloads such processing onto the RAID card. It depends on how you use the RAID, but this probably wont add significant load (CPU's are rather fast now..)
- Software RAID is infinitely cheaper, since it's (probably) included with your OS already
- A software RAID is more portable, tied to a specific operating system, rather than a specific RAID card brand or model (["RAID interoperability"](http://features.techworld.com/storage/1349/raid-interoperability/))
- (Personal opinion) Slightly unfounded, but I trust software RAID more than then drivers for RAID cards - software engineers are generally better at making software than hardware engineers!

One isn't better than the other - both have their advantages..

If you're concerned about performance, or need more drives than your motherboard will take, you should go with a RAID card (although it's worth trying/benchmarking software RAID before you buy a RAID card)

Answer (score 3):

Hardware usually has better support for hotswap with separate hardware logic/circuitry, easier identification of failed drives by blinking lights, bootable volumes for any raid level and so on... performance-wise? Not really, as long as there're cpu-cycles left and the software implementation is good enough...

...but as nik has pointed out - hardware isn't always "hardware" and generally "it depends".